# simple Xml object navigate issue

Tags: php, xml

i have an xml obj like thid:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => survey1_question01
            [num] => 01
            [text] => 1. What times will I take my 2 pills of Incivek (telaprevir) each day?
        )

    [response] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [dose1] => 08:00 AM
                    [dose2] => 12:02 PM
                    [dose3] => 08:00 PM
                )

        )
```

how can i navigate to [text] and [response]  ?. the problem is $xmlTxt->results->question[1]->@attributes  will not work . may be @ symbol is the reason how can i bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [attributes()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) to access xml attribues

`echo $xmlTxt->results->question[1]->attributes()->text;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access object properties with special characters use `{}` e.g.

```
$xmlTxt->results->question[1]->{'@attributes'}
```

Comment: for some reason it returns a null object like this SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)

Comment: still the problem exist ... $xmlTxt->results->question[1]->{'@attributes'} returns a null the attributes is an array i can access the way you said but i can't access the object .

Comment: @Compiler you code and the object dump doesn't match, I'd try `$obj->{'@attributes'}['text']` to get the text.